# Add new element in nested array in mongodb php

Tags: php, mongodb

I want to add a new element in array appusergoogleid. But I am getting error that i am adding object in array.

```
$id=array("id"=>$appusergoogleid);

$collection->update(array("appuseremail"=>$appuseremail),array('$push' => array('appusergoogleid'=>$id)));
```

This is the json in which i m inserting

```
 { 
   "_id":ObjectId("55cc982946449835298b4567"),
   "appuserfirstname":"demo",
   "appuserlastname":" appuserlastname",
   "appusermiddlename":"xyz",
   "appuseremail":"abc@gmail.com",
   "follows":"1",
   "appusergoogleid":{ 
      "id":"wemhjgh"
   },
   "usercreationdate":ISODate(   "2015-08-13T18:44:17Z"   ),
   "status":"0"
}
```

i want that whenever i add something in appusergoogleid, it makes an array there instead of object.

Comment: you want to insert your json data in `$collection`?

Comment: no, this is what i m getting at backend

Comment: `appusergoogleid" : { "id" : "wemhjgh" },` is **not** an array. A array looks like this `appusergoogleid" : [{ "id" : "wemhjgh" }]`. PHP is the only weird thing I know of that insists on referring to "objects" and "arrays" as the same thing. They are not. Either change your data or use the `$set` operator instead of `$push`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$filter = array('_id'=>$id));
$update = array('$addToSet'=>array('done_by'=>'2'));
$q->update($filter,$update);
```

> When you need to update use `$addToSet` so you avoid duplicate inserts
>   which leads to multiple entries.